# Nix how to simulate exact environment when a derivation is being built?

Tags: rust, nix, libgit2

So I'm doing a simple thing in my rust project which is updating a dependency on git2 from 0.13.25 to 0.14.2. I want to then make a complete build with Nix. When I do a nix-build `nix-build nix/ci -A actions.packages.alerting -K` (alerting is my project).

I get among other things output:

```
Building build.rs (libgit2_sys)
Running rustc --crate-name build_script_build build.rs --crate-type bin -C debuginfo=2 -C embed-bitcode=no --edition 2018 --cfg feature="default" --cfg feature="https" --cfg feature="libssh2-sys" --cfg feature="openssl-sys" --cfg feature="ssh" --cfg feature="ssh_key_from_memory" --out-dir target/build/libgit2-sys --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=target/buildDeps --extern cc=/nix/store/v311xp5vhjymxn9zk855cwihcwi0nj7z-rust_cc-1.0.72-lib/lib/libcc-8cc528ba2b.rlib --extern pkg_config=/nix/store/23mr9d754vngcrkphj9623pv3zchk3sk-rust_pkg-config-0.3.20-lib/lib/libpkg_config-39ea50320b.rlib --cap-lints allow --color always


error occurred: Command "gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "/build/libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2/target/build/libgit2-sys.out/include" "-I" "libgit2/src" "-I" "libgit2/deps/http-parser" "-I" "libgit2/deps/pcre" "-I" "/nix/store/pny40lfk2s01n2p7w5q8srg4nd5v3w6g-openssl-1.1.1m-dev/include" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DGIT_REGEX_BUILTIN=1" "-DHAVE_STDINT_H=1" "-DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1" "-DNO_RECURSE=1" "-DNEWLINE=10" "-DPOSIX_MALLOC_THRESHOLD=10" "-DLINK_SIZE=2" "-DPARENS_NEST_LIMIT=250" "-DMATCH_LIMIT=10000000" "-DMATCH_LIMIT_RECURSION=MATCH_LIMIT" "-DMAX_NAME_SIZE=32" "-DMAX_NAME_COUNT=10000" "-DSHA1DC_NO_STANDARD_INCLUDES=1" "-DSHA1DC_CUSTOM_INCLUDE_SHA1_C=\"common.h\"" "-DSHA1DC_CUSTOM_INCLUDE_UBC_CHECK_C=\"common.h\"" "-o" "/build/libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2/target/build/libgit2-sys.out/build/libgit2/src/transports/ssh.o" "-c" "libgit2/src/transports/ssh.c" with args "gcc" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).


note: keeping build directory '/tmp/nix-build-rust_libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2.drv-2'
builder for '/nix/store/ibipalg67ism9cwj4hdcj7ifdqzb2k8f-rust_libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/0zk6spayh52pappfw0xk6vny9ylmp7kj-rust_alerting-1.10.10-test.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/6364p4kmgangzqqzwgxrmlk260mv45kl-rust_alerting-1.10.10.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/555c1nrvqlzjz71qzyi3s8gjyf7xrxg8-rust_alerting-1.10.10-linked.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/555c1nrvqlzjz71qzyi3s8gjyf7xrxg8-rust_alerting-1.10.10-linked.drv' failed
```

I want to know why this gcc invocation is failing.
What I tried doing is going to this kept folder '/tmp/nix-build-rust_libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2.drv-2', running `. env-vars` and running `"gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "/build/libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2/target/build/libgit2-sys.out/include" "-I" "libgit2/src" "-I" "libgit2/deps/http-parser" "-I" "libgit2/deps/pcre" "-I" "/nix/store/pny40lfk2s01n2p7w5q8srg4nd5v3w6g-openssl-1.1.1m-dev/include" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DGIT_REGEX_BUILTIN=1" "-DHAVE_STDINT_H=1" "-DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1" "-DNO_RECURSE=1" "-DNEWLINE=10" "-DPOSIX_MALLOC_THRESHOLD=10" "-DLINK_SIZE=2" "-DPARENS_NEST_LIMIT=250" "-DMATCH_LIMIT=10000000" "-DMATCH_LIMIT_RECURSION=MATCH_LIMIT" "-DMAX_NAME_SIZE=32" "-DMAX_NAME_COUNT=10000" "-DSHA1DC_NO_STANDARD_INCLUDES=1" "-DSHA1DC_CUSTOM_INCLUDE_SHA1_C=\"common.h\"" "-DSHA1DC_CUSTOM_INCLUDE_UBC_CHECK_C=\"common.h\"" "-o" "/build/libgit2-sys-0.13.2+1.4.2/target/build/libgit2-sys.out/build/libgit2/src/transports/ssh.o" "-c" "libgit2/src/transports/ssh.c"` there.

The output I get is `In file included from libgit2/src/transports/ssh.h:10, from libgit2/src/transports/ssh.c:8: libgit2/src/common.h:11:11: fatal error: git2/sys/features.h: No such file or directory 11 | # include "git2/sys/features.h" |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

I believe this is not the same output I was getting when running nix-build.

Am I missing some step? I want to know the exact output of the gcc compilation so that I can report it to git2-rs repo or if there's a problem in our Nix infra to fix it somehow. I apologize if my question is poor quality; I'm really struggling with debugging nix builds and I've read stuff like https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nixpkgs/Create_and_debug_packages#Using_nix-shell_for_package_development but it's not helping

Comment: I know only a little bit about git2-rs, and nothing at all about nix. But I can give you some background on libgit2 that may be able to help you debug this. `git2/sys/features.h` is a required header that has your system's configuration information on it. (eg, are you on Windows and linking against the Windows crypto stack? Or Linux and OpenSSL? Are you using millisecond resolution timestamps? etc). This file is _generally_ generated by `cmake` when you're building libgit2. However, if git2-rs is doing the compilation then it ... presumably ... should create and configure that file.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following snippet from my cheat sheet is a good starting point for you:

```
nix-build --builders '' -K -A package
# path to the kept build directory under /tmp is shown
export out=/tmp/nix-build-package-1.0.0.drv-0
# the following might be required if you run into permission issues
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R $out
nix-shell -E --pure 'with import ./. { }; package'
bash --rcfile $out/env-vars
cd $out/
export TMP=$PWD TMPDIR=$PWD
# start debugging
buildPhase
...
```